# Why does LyX flag the following maths macro definition as an error?

Tags: lyx

The following macro is the LaTeX equivalent of a macro that
I defined using the LyX maths macro facility.

```
\global\long\def\fdd#1#2#3{\mathscr{F}^{\left(#1\right)}\left[#2_{#3}\right]}
```

LyX comes up with the following error when I compile my document:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\fdd #1#2#3->\mathscr {F}^{\left (#1\right )}\left [#2_{#3}\right ]
```

However, the following macro, in which `\mathscr` is replaced with `\textrm`, compiles successfully.

```
\global\long\def\fdd#1#2#3{\textrm{F}^{\left(#1\right)}\left[#2_{#3}\right]}
```

What could be wrong with the first macro?

Comment: `\mathscr` isn't defined in "basic" latex, so you probably have to load a package that defines it.  `euscript` and `mathrsfs` are two packages that do define this command.  i'm not a lyx user, so i can't say how to access them "natively".

Comment: Why `\global\long\def\fdd#1#2#3` and not `\newcommand{\fdd}[3]`?

Comment: Note that `LyX` is not flagging it as an error. That is a `LaTeX` error. `LyX` is just passing it on to you.

Comment: Thanks for all the responses. It works when I use the package mathrsfs. What is interesting is that the problem only occurs when the formal script font is used in a macro definition. When I use the formal script font in the body of a LyX document the error does not occur, even if I don't use the package mathrsfs explicitly. I therefore thought that the same condition would naturally be extended to the context of the use of the LyX maths macro definition facility. I was dead wrong! Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Add the package [`mathrsfs`](http://ctan.org/pkg/mathrsfs) to your preamble (Document > Settings... > LaTeX preamble) - it provides the functionality to use `\mathscr`.